# How to update or insert data into a table using a loop structure

Tags: php, mysql

Please assist me on this one. I have two DB's, one keeps track of user and system activities and the other keeps track of only user activities. The purpose of the codes below is to first of all retreive all tables from the second DB. These tables have the following columns:

(id |date |debit |credit |number |description |accounttype |company_id)

The idea is to retrieve all tables and only their |debit|credit| columns. Already these fields (|debit|credit|) have some values in them. After retrieval, I should be able to update or if possible do a new insertion to any or all the tables that have been retrieved from the DB.

Below are the codes I've written. It retrieves alright but can't do an insertion or update. Please assist me

The same page calls itself.

```
//Connection and Extraction from DB



//DB Connection exists


//SQL Query

$sql = "show tables from $companyname";

$results = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$count = 1;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))

{

 $results2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$row[0]` LIMIT 1") or die('Error'.mysql_error());

 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($results2))

 {

  $debit = $row2['debit'];

  $credit = $row2['credit'];

  echo "<tr><td>$count. </td><td width='30%'>".ucwords($row[0])."</td><td width='30%'>

<input type='text' name='debit' value='$debit' align='right'></td>

     <td width='30%'><input type='text' name='credit' value='$credit' align='right'></td></tr>";

 }

$count++;    

}

 //Insertion into DB  

if(isset($_POST['submit']))    {

//SQL Query

$sql3 = "show tables from $companyname";

$results3 = mysql_query($sql3) or die(mysql_error());

$count = 1;

while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($results3))

{

    $results4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$row3[0]` LIMIT 1") or die('Error '.mysql_error());

        $debit = $_POST['debit'];

        $credit = $_POST['credit'];     

    while($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($results4))

    {

        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `$row3[0]` SET `debit`= '$row4[debit]' , `credit`= '$row4[credit]' WHERE `id`=`$row4[id]`");

        echo "UPDATE `$row3[0]` SET `debit`= '$row4[debit]' , `credit`= '$row4[credit]' WHERE `id`=`$row4[id]` <br>";

        echo $num;

    }

$count++;         

}

}
```

Comment: why isn't all the data in the 2nd schema(/database) just a table in your first schema?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. The 1st schema contains a table that keeps record of a particular activity. This tables' PK is a FK in all the tables in the 2nd schema.

Comment: so you using multiple tables whit the same structure just to get an autoincrement for each one?

Answer (score 0):

1. your database design is bad
   I should have keepd all data in one schema, 
   keeping a seperate auto_increment by company by using a dubbel field primary key

   ```
   CREATE TABLE company_transaktions (
       company_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
       id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
       date DATE NOT NULL,
       debit FLOAT NOT NULL,
       credit FLOAT NOT NULL,
       number MENIUMINT NOT NULL,
       description TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
       accounttype TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
       company_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
       PRIMARY KEY (company_name,id)
   );
   ```

   or if company_id is what i think it is, you should use `PRIMARY KEY (company_id,id)`
2. the php problem

   you store your 2 postdata in 2 variables

   ```
   $debit = $_POST['debit'];
   $credit = $_POST['credit'];
   ```

   but you never use them, they are always going to be the value of the last row, as they all have the same name.

   so first thing you need to do is to rename your inputs:

   ```
   echo "<tr>\n";
   echo "<td>$count. </td>\n";
   echo "<td width='30%'>".ucwords($row[0])."</td>\n";
   echo "<td width='30%'><input type='text' name='{$row[0]}[debit]' value='$debit' align='right'></td>\n";
   echo "<td width='30%'><input type='text' name='{$row[0]}[credit]' value='$credit' align='right'>\n";
   echo "</td>\n";
   echo "</tr>";
   ```

   then you can fetch the right one on each loop:

   ```
   $debit = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$row3[0]]['debit']);
   $credit = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$row3[0]]['credit']);
   ```

   and then use them in your query

   ```
   $result = mysql_query("UPDATE `$row3[0]` SET `debit`= '$debit' , `credit`= '$credit' WHERE `id`=`$row4[id]`");
   ```

Comment: Assuming 5 tables were retrieved, when the "submit" key is pressed the update statement only sees the last table edit it as such and reset all the other tables to 0 whether or not something was entered into them.